# Apache Tomcat Windows stdout/stderr configuration

Tags: windows, stdout, stderr, java.util.logging, tomcat9

Like many other members before me, I have some questions surrounding configuring Apache Tomcat logging on Windows.  To be more specific, my questions surround the proper method(s) for limiting the size and number of log files that are created for stderr/stdout of the Apache Tomcat server as a whole.

My Java knowledge is pretty much limited to whatever I've been able to find on the web in searches.

What I believe I understand is this:

The Apache Tomcat service on Windows defaults to the -std(out|err).yyyy-mm-dd.log

The Apache Tomcat service uses the following options in the Java startup definition:

```
  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=<tomcat_home>\conf\logging.properties
```

The Apache Tomcat service defines the majority of its core logging options within the logging.properties file.

Is there a proper configuration/directive/option that can/should be added to the logging.properties file to limit the size, number, count, etc. of the std(out|err) log files?

My main confusion is with how the loggers and handlers are defined within the logging.properties file with respect to the Tomcat service itself.

If this has been answered in another thread that I didn't find before posting this, please redirect me.  I have tried to follow along with Apache's documentation for logging (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html) but I don't know if I can simply add options like `maxDays`, `count`, and `maxCapSize` (or whatever the appropriate option and value should be) directly into the <tomcat_home>\conf\logging.properties file or if I have to use a different way?

Any help or direction that gets me to a better understanding of this and how to accomplish my end goal of limiting the number and size of std(out|err) log files is and will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Greg

Comment: Almost 2 weeks with no activity.  Anyone have any suggestions or redirection to other posts that might be able to help answer my question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apache Tomcat 9 Windows Service How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) There are only the following options:

```
--LogPath   %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Apache   Defines the path for logging.  Creates the directory if necessary.
--LogPrefix commons-daemon  Defines the service log filename prefix. The log file is created in the LogPath directory with .YEAR-MONTH-DAY.log suffix
--LogLevel  Info    Defines the logging level and can be either Error, Info, Warn or Debug. (Case insensitive).
--StdOutput     Redirected stdout filename. If named auto then file is created inside LogPath with the name service-stdout.YEAR-MONTH-DAY.log.
--StdError      Redirected stderr filename. If named auto then file is created inside LogPath with the name service-stderr.YEAR-MONTH-DAY.log.
```

Looks like for deleting of files you would have to create a scheduled task to do so.

Comment: I've added these options to the Service definition in Windows (tomcatw.exe //ES//<servicename>

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=E:\Apps\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0.11\conf\logging.properties
-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10240000
-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
-Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.append = false

It appears to at least keep the stdout/stderr files in check. If no one else has a better/different answer, I'll mark this question as answered.

Comment: The above configuration in service definition is not working, is there any other alternative?

Comment: @Beschi Open a new question as we'll need more background on what [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) means.  One alternative is listed in the existing answer.  As you can see in the answer the Tomcat service itself has only a few tuning options and nothing to deal with deleting of stdout and stderr files.